# MySQL: Filter one order number (appears in multiple rows) that has specific values in another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of orders where each order has a different ticket id and status for each ticket in the order.

| order_id | ticket_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2347346 | 77463612 | 0 |
| 2347346 | 77463613 | 16 |
| 2347346 | 77463614 | 20 |
| 2347346 | 77463615 | 5 |
| 9997876 | 77423474 | 6 |
| 9997876 | 77423475 | 12 |
| 9997876 | 77423476 | 20 |
| 9997876 | 77423477 | 9 |

etc...

This is a very large database spanning years, so I am looking to write a query that would give me every order_id that has a ticket with a status `IN (2,16,20)` and a ticket with `status=0`. Using the table above, I should have order `2347346` return in the results, but not order `9997876`. Any creative ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Write one subquery that gets order_id with `status IN (2,16,20)` and another with `status = 0`. Then join these two subqueries to get order with both.

Comment: You can also use `WHERE EXISTS (...)` with a correlated subquery.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean by 'and' in: "order_id that has a ticket with a status IN (2,16,20) and a ticket with status=0". AND will imply you always get exactly 0 results whilst OR would mean simplifying the clause  just to status IN (0,2,16,20). so `select distinct order_id from table where status in (0,2,16,20 )`

Comment: How about `SELECT order_id FROM mytable GROUP BY order_id HAVING SUM(status = 0) >= 1 AND SUM(status IN (2,16,20)) >= 1`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and help. I'm sorry if my question seems vague, i just was looking for appropriate strategies to try because I am also joining this table with others in order to determine certain information from data similarities involving package names and such. With your suggestions, I'm returning the data wanted for the most part, now I'm just refactoring to decrease run time and extract more relevant info. Cheers!